# How to extract the required lines in squid.conf file

Tags: command-line, squid

How do i take out the commented lines in the `squid.conf` file and make the newly created squid file the default config file for my squid proxy server ?

Answer (score 1):

How about `sed` :

```
sed -i.bak '/^#/d' /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

The original file will be saved as `/etc/squid/squid.conf.bak`. If you don't want to save the original file, use:

```
sed -i '/^#/d' /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

Or `grep` :

```
grep -v '^#' /etc/squid/squid.conf > /etc/squid/squid.conf.bak && mv /etc/squid/squid.conf.bak /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

I will not suggest you to just blindly remove all the lines starting with `#` as they may contain various important info/suggestions.